# Tengo estos valores y aun no me deja hacer el insert

Tags: php

```
            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (";
    $sql .= "CUM, Nombre, A_Pat, A_Mat, Sexo, F_Naci, Vigencia, Provincia, Grupo_S, Seccion, Scouter_Responsable,";
    $sql .= "Tel_Cel, Password, Estatura, Peso, Color_Cabello, Color_Ojos, Color_Piel, Tipo_Sangre, Donar_Sangre, Dieta, Alcohol,";
    $sql .= "Fumador, Uso_Sustancias,Fam_Diabetes, Fam_Hipertension, Afecciones_Frio_Calor, Fk_Info_Emergencia, Fk_Regnal, Tipo_Usuario";
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    $sql .= ":cum,'".$this->Nombre."', :ap_pa, :ap_ma, :sexo,'".$this->F_Nac."','".$this->Vigencia."',:provincia,:grupo,:seccion,:scouterR,:celular,:passuser,:estatura,";
    $sql .= ":peso,'".$this->Color_Cabello."',:color_ojos,:color_piel,'".$this->Tipo_Sangre."',:donarsangre,:dieta,'".$this->Alcohol."',:fuma,:sustanciasrecreativas,'".$this->Fam_Diabetes."',";
    $sql .= ":familiahipertension,:afecciones,'1','jalo000001',:tipouser)";
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $consulta->bindParam(':cum', $this->CUM);//1
    $consulta->bindParam(':nombre', $this->Nombre);//2
    $consulta->bindParam(':ap_pa', $this->A_Pat);//3
    $consulta->bindParam(':ap_ma', $this->A_Mat);//4
    $consulta->bindParam(':sexo', $this->Sexo);//5
    $consulta->bindParam(':fechadenacimiento', $this->F_Nac);//6
    $consulta->bindParam(':vigenciascout', $this->Vigencia);//7
    $consulta->bindParam(':provincia', $this->Provincia);//8
    $consulta->bindParam(':grupo', $this->Grupo_S);//9
    $consulta->bindParam(':seccion', $this->Seccion);//10
    $consulta->bindParam(':scouterR', $this->Scouter_Responsable);//11
    $consulta->bindParam(':celular', $this->Tel_Cel);//12
    $consulta->bindParam(':passuser', $this->Password);//13
    $consulta->bindParam(':estatura', $this->Estatura);//14
    $consulta->bindParam(':peso', $this->Peso);//15
    $consulta->bindParam(':color_cabello', $this->Color_Cabello);//16
    $consulta->bindParam(':color_ojos', $this->Color_Ojos);//17
    $consulta->bindParam(':color_piel', $this->Color_Piel);//18
    $consulta->bindParam(':tiposangre', $this->Tipo_Sangre);//19
    $consulta->bindParam(':donarsangre', $this->Donar_Sangre);//20
    $consulta->bindParam(':dieta', $this->Dieta);//21
    $consulta->bindParam(':bebealcohol', $this->Alcohol);//22
    $consulta->bindParam(':fuma', $this->Fumador);//23
    $consulta->bindParam(':sustanciasrecreativas', $this->Uso_Sustancias);//24
    $consulta->bindParam(':familiadiabetes', $this->Fam_Diabetes);//25
    $consulta->bindParam(':familiahipertension', $this->Fam_Hipertension);//26
    $consulta->bindParam(':afecciones', $this->Afecciones_Frio_Calor);//27
    //$consulta->bindParam(':infoemerg', '1');
    //$consulta->bindParam(':regnalito', 'JAL0290507');
    $consulta->bindParam(':tipouser', $this->Tipo_Usuario);//28
   // var_dump($consulta);

    if (!$consulta || !$consultaEmergencia)
    {
        $this->mensaje = $mensaje = $conexion->errorInfo();
    }else {
        //$consultaEmergencia->execute();
        $consulta->execute();
        $this->mensaje = "Se hizo el insert";
    }
```

Comment: por que segmentas tanto la query?, no sería mas simple y legible meter todo el insert dentro de un solo par de `""` e indentarla para leerla mas simple?

Comment: Pero ¿te muestra algún error cuando tratas de hacer un insert? ¿cuál es el sql específico que estás tratando de ejecutar?. Mas información

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Esta parte de tu consulta es totalmente errónea:

```
$sql .= ":cum,'".$this->Nombre."', :ap_pa, :ap_ma, :sexo,'".$this->F_Nac."','".$this->Vigencia."',:provincia,:grupo,:seccion,:scouterR,:celular,:passuser,:estatura,";
$sql .= ":peso,'".$this->Color_Cabello."',:color_ojos,:color_piel,'".$this->Tipo_Sangre."',:donarsangre,:dieta,'".$this->Alcohol."',:fuma,:sustanciasrecreativas,'".$this->Fam_Diabetes."',";
$sql .= ":familiahipertension,:afecciones,'1','jalo000001',:tipouser)";
```

En consultas preparadas no puedes hacer cosas como estas:

<s>`":cum,'".$this->Nombre."',`</s>

Los marcadores deben ir aparte, uno tras otro y los valores aparte, sea mediante un método *bind*, sea en el `execute` (pues PDO ofrece la ventaja de pasar los datos en forma de array en el `execute` lo cual es una ventaja interesante, sobre todo para casos como el tuyo).

Dado que la consulta es muy larga y te puedes equivocar con algún marcador de `:nombre`, puedes usar marcadores de posición `?`, y pasar los datos en forma de array en `execute`. De ese modo hay menos riesgo de error. Lo que sí debes verificar es que la cantidad de marcadores coincidad exactamente y que en el array tengan las posiciones correspondientes.

Te propongo modificar el código así:

```
/*Consulta lo más sencilla posible con marcadores de posición*/
$sql = 
    "INSERT INTO usuario 
        (
            CUM, 
            Nombre, 
            A_Pat, 
            A_Mat, 
            Sexo, 
            F_Naci, 
            Vigencia, 
            Provincia, 
            Grupo_S, 
            Seccion, 
            Scouter_Responsable,
            Tel_Cel, 
            Password, 
            Estatura, 
            Peso, 
            Color_Cabello, 
            Color_Ojos, 
            Color_Piel, 
            Tipo_Sangre, 
            Donar_Sangre, 
            Dieta, 
            Alcohol,
            Fumador, 
            Uso_Sustancias,
            Fam_Diabetes, 
            Fam_Hipertension, 
            Afecciones_Frio_Calor, 
            Fk_Info_Emergencia, 
            Fk_Regnal, 
            Tipo_Usuario
        )
    VALUES 
        (
            ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
        )
    ";



    if (!$consulta || !$consultaEmergencia)  
    {
        $this->mensaje = $mensaje = $conexion->errorInfo();
    }else {

    /*Datos que pasaremos en el execute*/   
    $arrParams=array 
            (
                $this->CUM,
                $this->Nombre,
                $this->A_Pat,
                $this->A_Mat,
                $this->Sexo,
                $this->F_Nac,
                $this->Vigencia,
                $this->Provincia,
                $this->Grupo_S,
                $this->Seccion,
                $this->Scouter_Responsable,
                $this->Tel_Cel,
                $this->Password,
                $this->Estatura,
                $this->Peso,
                $this->Color_Cabello,
                $this->Color_Ojos,
                $this->Color_Piel,
                $this->Tipo_Sangre,
                $this->Donar_Sangre,
                $this->Dieta,
                $this->Alcohol,
                $this->Fumador,
                $this->Uso_Sustancias,
                $this->Fam_Diabetes,
                $this->Fam_Hipertension,
                $this->Afecciones_Frio_Calor,
                '1',
                'JAL0290507',
                $this->Tipo_Usuario
            );

        $consulta->execute($arrParams);
        $this->mensaje = "Se hizo el insert"; //deberías verificar con affected_rows
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, apenas me estoy introduciendo en el mundo del PDO y me ayudo bastante. Saludos, ahora lo voy a probar.

Comment: ¡Sí funciono!, Graciass